# Как поместить в стек C++ локальную переменную Lua?

Tags: c++, lua

Здравствуйте,
есть таблица луа:

```
local tb = {};
tb.t_1={};
tb.t_2={};
```

Мне нужно из C++ получить к ним доступ (они обязательно должны быть помечены как local, это требование другой программы с которой работаю)
Подскажите как это сделать. вроде есть lua_getlocal но там нужно переменную как то по индексу указывать, это не сильно понятно мне. Может есть способ выцепить ее по имени таблицы ?

Comment: Поскольку переменная локальная, то она существует только в какой-то определённый промежуток времени. Например, только внутри функции. И чтобы в С++ получить значение этой переменной в какой-то определённый момент, вы можете передать её своей сишной функции.

Comment: Если речь о модуле, и в конце модуля есть строчка `return tb`, то эту таблицу можно получить вот так: https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2016/01/07/using-lua-with-c-in-practice-part4/

Comment: Благодарю, нашел возможность использовать глобальную вместо локальных переменных.